# Unable to set elementId of a view into list content id

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that renders a list elements using the following template :

```
   {{#each item in controller}}
       {{view App.ItemView}}        
    {{/each}}
```

I need the id of each item the be the id of corresponding itemView. Here is my first attempt but it doesn't work :

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId: Ember.computed(function(){
        return this.getPath('item.id');
    }),
    templateName: 'item'
});
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

You can find a jsfiddle illustrating my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/jrabary/vk4Ze/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the view need to compute the `elementId` property, `item` is not yet set, so here the problems are starting...

If you want to set the id once the item is available, you will have to allow Ember to retrieve the DOM element to alter... That means Ember has to set the element's id!
In other words, it is impossible as of today, as Ember uses elements id to keep references on its DOM owned/controlled elements.

Nevertheless, the view has the displayed item bound to it, so you can retrieve the item later. What is exactly you underlying need?

**EDIT**

Here is a sample customizing element's class according to item's id: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/ZAHxm/

Comment: I need to test my application from the outside. For this I'm using cucumber and capybara. There, I want to test a click on a element using find(:xpath, "//div[@id='elementId']") that's why I need the element id. But I can change the way I do this.

Comment: I have an example setting a class according to item's id @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/ZAHxm/

Comment: And just one quick note, don't set `elementId`. Ember sets that property on every view. You should change the name to something else like `contentId`.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers helped me. In the end I wanted to set the ID attribute of the view's wrapping tag specifically to be the model's ID. I found you can use the view's didInsertElement hook to achieve that by accessing the currently-rendered element's context with this.get('context').get('anyProperty') and the DOM element itself (as jQuery object) with this.$(). Seems long-winded but couldn't see the cleaner way.

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'MyTemplate',
    didInsertElement: function(e){
        this.$().attr('id', this.get('context').get('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this interfere with Ember's internal bookkeeping? I assume it set the `id` attribute it did for a reason.

Comment: Does it have side effects?